# How to display graphs in Shinken?

Tags: ubuntu, monitor

I am trying to  monitor my Linux servers using Shinken. I installed Graphite for graphs by following this link: [install graphite](http://alfredocambera.blogspot.be/2014/06/graphite-on-nginxuwsgi-debian-wheezy.html) and after that I followed the link: [Enabling graphs on your shinken monitor](http://blog.adimian.com/2014/12/enabling-graphs-on-your-shinken-monitor/). It's running fine but in my Shinken dashboard it shows an empty graph image like the one below.

[image]

Where exactly is my mistake?

Comment: check also that you have pytz installed, and open the broken image to a new tab to see if graphite is throwing you a traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your ui-graphite.cfg file :

```
/etc/shinken/modules/ui-graphite.cfg
```

And change uri like this :

```
http://YOURSERVERNAME/ > http://<ip to graphite>:8080/
```

This should work...